# Descendent pseudo before and after markup

Tags: css

Is it really not possible to target child pseudo classes?

I need somehow to style or more second descendent `::before` and `::after` classes.

[image]

Example, here I'd like to visually make different second `::before` (around 'First' list item)

Thanks

```css
*::before {
  background-color: green;
}

*::after {
  background-color: red;
}

::after,
 ::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .7;
}

::before ::before {
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Some nice lists!</h3>
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is related to my little project on codepen so you can see full code here > `https://codepen.io/kpendic/pen/OeJwoz?editors=1100`

Comment: There is nothign like `second :before`, `:after:before`, etc. If you need another element, just add it into your HTML. Or tell us what you need to do, maybe the current markup will be okay and you can style existing (pseudo)elements.

Comment: hey @panther if you take a look on css you can see that every element for ex. get green dot (kind of like a start of element) .. and in case of UL and first LI element that both green dots are on same place.. I'd like to move a little second dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to comment, when 2 `:before` elements are over themselves, you can move one of them.

Eg.

```
ul:before {margin-top: -10px;} /* move 10px above LI:before */
```

OR

```
ul > li:first-child:before {margin-left: -10px;} /* move just 1st LIs :before */
```

This way you need to browse all places where 2 `:before/after` elements are in the same position (where parent and 1st child has the same position, etc.)

Comment: ok man thanks, marking it as solution.. didn't know that parent>child rel can't exist in pseudo.. will need to go event further .. need to mark inputs similarly etc.. but this is start for now :)

Comment: @KresimirPendic: each :before/:after is `> child` of element in real. Exactly the first and the last one, but untargetable using `>` selector.